# why does MyBatis override SQL values in DB?

Tags: mybatis

I have a strange problem where I set the default value in my class:

```
class Foo {
  Double bar = 0.9;
}
```

and map it my XML:

```
<result column="bar" property="bar"/>
```

I have a record in the DB where bar is NULL

However when I use my MyBatis getFoo call:

```
<select id="findAll" resultMap="Foo">
    <![CDATA[
    select * from foo;
]]>
</select>
```

I am seeing the value of 0.9 even though in the DB it is NULL

Comment: See the [SSCCE guide](http://sscce.org/) for how to prepare a good example. The best way, IMHO, is to share a small executable demo project with assertions. [Here](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) are some project templates/examples for MyBatis.